# Deploy application on AWS VPC

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am planning to migrate from Ec2 classic to EC2 VPC. My application reads messages from SQS, download assets from S3 and perform actions mentioned in the SQS messages and then updates RDS. I have following queries

1. Is it beneficial for me to migrate to Amazon VPC from Classic
2. I create my EC2 machines using ruby scripts, and deploy code on them using capistrano. In classic mode I used the IP address to deploy code using capistrano. But in VPC there is a concept of private IP address and you cannot access a machine inside a subnet.So my question is:
   How should I deploy code on the EC2 instances or rather how should I connect to them?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This questions is pretty broad but I'll take stab at it:

> Is it beneficial for me to migrate to Amazon VPC from Classic

It's beneficial if you care about security of your data in transit and at rest. In a VPC none of your traffic is exposed to the outside and you can chose which components you want to expose in case you want to receive traffic/data from the outside. i.e Your ELB or ELBs.

> I create my EC2 machines using ruby scripts, and deploy code on them using capistrano. In classic mode I used the IP address to deploy
>   code using capistrano. But in VPC there is a concept of private IP
>   address and you cannot access a machine inside a subnet. So my question
>   is: How should I deploy code on the EC2 instances or rather how should
>   I connect to them?

You can actually assign a public IP to your EC2 machines in a VPC if you choose to. You can use that IP to deploy your code from the outside.

You can read about it here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html

If you want more security you can always deploy from a machine in your VPC (that has SSH access to the outside). You can ssh to that machine and then run `cap deploy` from there.